# Reading user input in a script piped to the interpreter

Tags: bash

I want to get the user input in a bash script that is first downloaded via wget (proxied in the examble below using cat) and then fed into bash through stdin. I thought it would be straightforward but it doesn't work.

The script (in a file called gistfile2.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "Enter path: "
read path
echo $path
```

How I run it:

```
root@precise32:/tmp# cat (or wget -qO-) gistfile2.sh | bash 
Enter path: root@precise32:/tmp#
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This runs fine if you do `./gistfile2.sh`. It takes input and echoes it back to the screen....

Comment: @RespectMyAuthoritah yep but I want to host it on Github gist and then just wget/curl it and pipe it to the bash command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's look at how pipelines work:

When

```
foo | bar
```

runs `bar`, bar's stdin is connected to `foo`'s stdout. *This means that `bar` has no way of knowing what stdin descriptor it would have inherited were it not for the pipeline overriding it.* This information is lost, and cannot be recovered.

However, in practice, one can often guess: If `stderr` is still a TTY handle, that can be opened for stdin; and if the operating system provides a facility such as `/dev/tty` to get a handle on the process's controlling tty, all the better.

---

So:

If your stdin (FD 0) has been overridden by a pipeline, you can try to read from `/dev/tty`. **This is not by any means guaranteed to work, and is heavily platform-dependent functionality** -- but if it doesn't work, then you'll be falling back on other hackery such as hoping that stderr hasn't been redirected.

To read from `/dev/tty`:

```
read path </dev/tty || { rc=$?; echo "Unable to read from TTY" >&2; exit "$rc"; }
```

To read from stderr (assuming that it's connected to a read/write FD going to your TTY -- a big assumption):

```
read path <&2 || { rc=$?; echo "stderr not attached to a TTY?" >&2; exit "$rc"; }
```

Comment: Tried this and it works. Still trying to wrap my head around it though.

Comment: If you have any specific questions, or if there's a piece of my explanation that didn't make sense, let me know and I'll try to clarify.

Comment: I get the part where you have to read from /dev/tty because the pipeline was overriden. What does it mean exactly when a pipeline is overriden? The "bar" process think it has a real stdin but in fact it has a pipe? So when it tries to read from what it thinks is a real stdin, it's actually the pipe which returns something else.

Comment: It's not the pipeline that's overridden -- it's file descriptor #0, called stdin, that's overridden with input from the prior part of the pipeline (and for anything but the last piece of the pipeline, file descriptor #1, stdout, is overridden to go to the next element of the pipeline, not "real" stdout). So yes, when bar tries to read from stdin, it gets foo's stdout, not whatever "real" stdin would be.